# map with for of and reduce in js to make the sum

Tags: javascript

**I am trying to calculate a sum of prices. But I get the result 4350, but I need 4. Thanks for the answer

```js
let arr = [
  { price: 4 },
  { price: -120 },
  { price: -505 }, 
  { price: '350' },
];

let countArr = arr.map(elem => {
  return (elem.price > 0 ? elem.price : 0 && typeof(elem.price) ? elem.price : 0)
});

let sum = countArr.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: What is that `for` loop supposed to do…‽

Comment: Why do you have both `for` and `map`? They're both iterating over the same array.

Comment: There's no `arr.price`. `price` is a property of the array elements, not the array itself, so it should be `elem.price`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked to point out I won't give solution. But basically you can do it with one loop, reducing the sum of each item's `price` property (remember object.price = something).

If you do want to do it with 2 loops (since the reduce loop of yours is working), then first indeed `map` the array of objects to an array of prices, (again, remember item.price = something).

Update:
Given the now understood requirement of summing only **positive** and type of **number** prices:

```js
let arr = [
  { price: 4 },
  { price: -120 },
  { price: -505 }, 
  { price: '350' },
];
let countArr = arr.map(elem => {
  if (typeof(elem.price) !== "number") {
    return 0;
  }
  if (elem.price < 0) {
    return 0
  }
  return elem.price
});

let sum = countArr.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);

console.log(sum);

// for fun entire solution in one line:
console.log(arr.reduce((prev, {price}) => prev + (typeof(price) !== 'number' || price < 0 ? 0 : price), 0));
```

Comment: I made regarding your advice and I got the result but if I will make the price equaling "430", I get result:    number+430    ...Please help to solve the problem:

let countArr = arr.map(elem  => {

  return (elem.price > 0 ? elem.price : 0 && typeof elem.price === 'number' ? elem.price : 0)


});

let sum = countArr.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);

console.log(sum);

Comment: You can convert anything to number by adding `+` before it. So: `+elem.price + +previous` is ok.

Comment: no, I want "430" to be a 0 at the end and it will not be in a sum (&& typeof(elem.price) ? elem.price : 0 does not work)

Comment: You can explain it better if you [edit] your question and show the code and the expected result given an input etc.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provide I deduced you want to neglect values less than 0 this code do it in a simple and readable manner with one operation

```js
let arr = [
  { price: 4 },
  { price: -120 },
  { price: -505 }, 
  { price: 350 },
];

let sum = arr.reduce((a,b) => a + (b.price > 0 ? b.price : 0) , 0) 

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: let arr = [
  { price: 4 },
  { price: -120 },
  { price: -505 }, 
  { price: '350' },
];

let countArr = arr.map(elem => {

  return elem.price


});

let sum = arr.reduce((a,b) => a + (b.price > 0 ? b.price : 0 && b.price === 'number' ? b.price : 0) , 0) 

console.log(sum);

I got the result 4350, how to fix this? ;)

Comment: let arr = [{ price: 4 }, { price: -120 }, { price: -505 }, { price: '350' }];
let countArr = arr.map(elem => { return elem.price });
let sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + ( (b.price > 0 && typeof b.price === 'number' ) ? b.price : 0) , 0) 
console.log(sum)

check out this code

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the `Array.map()` function to check at the beginning whether the variable is a number or less than 0:

```js
let arr = [
  { price: 4 },
  { price: -120 },
  { price: -505 }, 
  { price: '350' },
];

let countArr = arr.map(elem => {
  return typeof elem.price === 'number' && elem.price > 0 ? elem.price : 0
});

let sum = countArr.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);

console.log(sum);
```